# C# "A registration already exists for URI" XAML Warning

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm currently working on a "server-app" / "client-app" project where the goal is to get some data from the server-app to the client app. I tried this with a WCF approach but since I've never worked with WCF it ain't an easy task for me.

So what I've already set up are the two apps in one solution à two different projects. Project one contains the server-app (TRunnerServer) and project two contains the client-app (TRunnerClient).

I've setup the interface for the service like that (in ServerApp MainWindowViewModel.cs):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITRunnerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<Program> GetProgramList();
}
```

Than I've added the method to the class etc. like following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, ITRunnerService
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Program> GetProgramList()
        {
            return this.ProgramList;
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            var uris = new Uri[1];
            string addr = "net.tcp://localhost:7000/MainWindowViewModel";
            uris[0] = new Uri(addr);
            ITRunnerService tRunnerService = this;
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(tRunnerService, uris);
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITRunnerService), binding, string.Empty);
            host.Open();
        }
}
```

Now in the GUI of the application TRunnerClient I've got an button that I press to get the data from the TRunnerServer App.
I've just got an method binded with following:

```
private void Refresh(object parameter)
{
var uri = "net.tcp://localhost:7000/MainWindowViewModel";
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
var channel = new ChannelFactory<ITRunnerService>(binding);
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
var proxy = channel.CreateChannel(endPoint);
this.ProgramList = proxy.GetProgramList();
}
```

Yet when I start the app only the client starts normal and the server app gives an exception based on the error warning from the xaml "A registration already exists for URI 'net.tcp://localhost:7000/MainWindowViewModel'".

How could I solve this problem?

***Note: Other questions with a similar title didn't really helped me out before someone strikes it as duplicate.***

Comment: Are you creating multiple `ServiceHosts` with the same base address or do you run more than one server process at once? How many instance of the `MainWindowViewModel` class are created?

Comment: @mm8 it already throws an exception before the first one is created as soon as I get to host.Open().

Comment: Make sure that there is no old sever process still hanging around.

Comment: @mm8 thanks for the answer! I was able to kill the hanging process and after that it worked. How can I make sure that there is no server process left hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that there is an old server process still hanging around. Try to kill it in the task manager and try again.

In order to avoid hanging processes, make sure that you exit the application gracefully and that you don't create any windows that you don't show and close.